# If $\mu$ is an infinitely divisible probability measure on $[0,\infty)$, then the Lévy measure of $\mu$ is the vague limit of $n\mu^{*1/n}$

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, levy-processes, infinite-divisibility

If $\nu$ is a finite measure on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$, let $\nu^{\ast k}$ denote the $k$-fold convolution¹ of $\nu$ with itself for $k\in\mathbb N_0$, $$\exp(\nu)\mathrel{:=}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\nu^{\ast k}}{k!}$$ and $$\operatorname{CPoi}_\nu\mathrel{:=}\frac{\exp(\nu)}{\exp(\nu)(\mathbb R)}.$$ Moreover, let $$\mathcal L_\nu(t)\mathrel{:=}\int\nu({\rm d}x)e^{-tx}\;\;\;\text{for $t\in\mathbb R$}$$ denote the Laplace transform of $\nu$.

> Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$. Remember that $\mu$ is called **infinitely divisible** if for all $k\in\mathbb N$, there is a probability measure $\nu$ on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ with $\mu=\nu^{\ast k}$.
>
> We can show that
>
> 1. $\mu$ is infinitely divisible;
>
> and
>
> 2. There is a sequence $(\nu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of finite measures on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ with $\operatorname{CPoi}_{\nu_n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\mu$ weakly
>
> are equivalent.

> Now assume $\mu$ is a probability measure on $([0,\infty),\mathcal B([0,\infty)))$. By the Lévy-Khinchin formula,
>
> 3. $\mu$ is infinitely divisible;
>
> and
>
> 4. There is a $\alpha\ge0$ and a $\sigma$-finite measure $\nu$ on $((0,\infty),\mathcal B((0,\infty)))$ with $$-\ln\mathcal L_\mu(t)=\alpha t+\int1-e^{-tx}\:\nu({\rm d}x)\;\;\;\text{for all $t\ge0$}\tag4$$
>
> are equivalent.
>
> **Question**: How can we show that if (3.) holds, then the $\nu$ from (4.) is equal to the vague limit² of $\left.n\mu^{\ast1/n}\right|_{(0,\:\infty)}$?

---

¹ I.e. $\nu^{\ast 0}:=\delta_0$ is the Dirac measure on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ at $0$ and if $k\in\mathbb N$, then $\nu^{\ast k}$ is the pushforward $\tau_k\left(\nu^{\otimes k}\right)$ of the $k$-fold product measure $\nu^{\otimes k}$ of $\nu$ with itself under the map $$\tau_k:\mathbb R^k\to\mathbb R\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto x_1+\dotsb+x_k.$$

² I.e. $$n\int_{(0,\:\infty)}f\:{\rm d}\mu^{\ast1/n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\int f\:{\rm d}\nu\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in C_0((0,\infty))\tag5.$$

Comment: This follows from the general fact that if $\mu_t = \mu^{*t}$ for $t > 0$, then $t^{-1} \mu_t$ converges vaguely in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ to the Lévy measure $\nu$. This, in turn, is closely related to the fact that if $p_t f = f * \mu_t$, then $t^{-1} (p_t f - f)$ converges to the *generator* applied to $f$ whenever $f$ is $C^2$. You should be able to find these facts in most books on Lévy processes, such as the one by Sato, but I do not have an exact reference at hand.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki How do you define $\mu^{\ast t}$ for non-integer $t$? And with generator, do you mean the $C_c^\infty$-generator of $p_t$?

Comment: In the same way as $\mu^{*1/n}$ in your question. For example, the characteristic function of $\mu$ is $e^{\phi(z)}$ for a negative definite $\phi$, and the characteristic function of $\mu^{*t}$ is $e^{t \phi(z)}$ for $t \geqslant 0$. This is all very standard, you may have a look at, say, Sato's *Lévy processes and infinitely divisible distributions*, Sections 7 and 8.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki I've taken a look at Sato. Is the measure $\mu^\ast t$ uniquely determined by $\mu$ (assuming $\mu$ is infinitely divisible) for irrational $t$? Or to state this question differently: Is $\mu^{\ast t}$ the unique probability measure on $\mathbb R^d$ such that $$\varphi_{\mu^{\ast t}}=\varphi_\mu^t$$ for all $t\ge0$? The uniqueness is clear to me for rational $t$.

Comment: I do not have access to Sato at the moment, so I am not sure how he defines $\mu^{*t}$, but in any case it is unique. Either uniquely determined by the characteristic function, or uniquely defined as the weak* limit of approximations by rational powers.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thank you for your comment. Do these results generalize to Banach spaces?

Comment: My intuition breaks in infinite dimensions, but I think the answer is "yes". Dave Applebaum likely discusses this (or at least gives some references) in his review article *Lévy processes and stochastic integrals in Banach spaces*, available at the [PMS website](http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~pms/files/27.1/Article/27.1.3.pdf).

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki How do we see that $\mu^{\ast t}$ is equivalently uniquely defined as the weak limit? For example, suppose $X$ is Lévy in law and $\mu:=\mathcal L(X_1)$. It then clearly holds $\mathcal L(X_t)=\mu^{\ast t}$ for all $t\in\mathbb Q\cap[0,\infty)$. Now taking $t>0$ and $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb Q\cap[0,\infty)$ with $t_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}t$, we clearly have $X_{t_n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}X_t$ in distribution (assuming $X$ is at least continuous in probability).

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Does $\mathcal L(X_t)=\mu^{\ast t}$ now simply follow from $\varphi_\mu^{t_n}=\varphi_{\mu^{\ast t_n}}=\varphi_{X_{t_n}}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\varphi_{X_t}$ and the former definition of $\mu^\ast$ in terms of characteristic functions?

Comment: I am sorry, I am lost. I do not even know how *you* define rational convolutive powers of $\mu$, so I am afraid I cannot help.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Sato shows that for each infinitely divisible characteristic function $\varphi$ of a probability measure $\mu$, there is a unique continuous $\psi$ with$\psi(0)=0$ and $\varphi=e^\psi$. He then shows that for all $k$, the unique continuous $g$ with $g(0)=1$ and $\varphi=g^k$ is given by $g=e^{\frac\psi k}$. Now he defines $\varphi^t:=e^{t\psi}$ for $t\ge0$. So, for rational $t$, there is a unique probability measure $\nu$ with $\mu=v^{\ast1/t}$ and $\varphi_\nu=\varphi^t$. Now we define $\mu^{\ast t}:=\nu$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki BTW, I'm still searching for a reference for $(5)$ and for $\alpha=\sup\left\{x\ge0:\mu([0,x))=0\right\}$. Sato doesn't contain these claims and I didn't find them in other books.

Comment: It looks like what you are missing is the link between weak convergence of probability distributions and pointwise convergence of the corresponding characteristic functions. This immediately proves (5) and uniqueness of $\mu^{*t}$ from what you wrote in your comment above.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki No, I'm actually aware of the link. I'll have a second look at that. However, regarding the actual question, what I was really missing is that - since we are dealing with probability measures - the notion of vague and weak convergence should coincide, right? And do you know how we can prove or do you have a reference for the formula for $\alpha$?

Comment: Regarding the support of $\mu$: I am sure this is answered in Section 24 of Sato's book, titled "Supports". (To be more constructive: if $\alpha$ is the left edge of the support of $\mu$, then $\mu_t(A) = \mu(A - t)$ is infinitely divisible and its support is still in $[0, \infty)$. And, of course, the Laplace transform of $\mu$ is $e^{-t}$ times the Laplace transform of $\mu_t$. Is this what you were asking about?)

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki (a) You didn't respond to my equivalence of weak/vague convergence. am I missing something? (b) I will take a look at that section of Sato's book. Regarding what you wrote about $\alpha$: $\alpha$ is not occurring in what you wrote after "then"; so, I'm afraid, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: (a) You are asking very basic questions that you can easily answer yourself, for example, by searching the web. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313986/are-vague-convergence-and-weak-convergence-of-measures-both-weak-convergence) on Math.SE, for example. (b) Change $e^{-t}$ to $e^{-\alpha t}$ in my comment.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thank you for your help so far. I've almost figured out how we can show the desired claim. Please take a look at my (partial) answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/375322/91890. Can you help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three ways to show that $n \mu^{*1/n}$ converges to $\nu$ vaguely in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. Let $X_t$ be the Lévy process such that $X_1$ has distribution $\mu$, and let $f$ be a smooth, compactly supported $f$ on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. It is sufficient to show that $t^{-1} \mathbb{E} f(X_t) \to \int f(x) \nu(dx)$ as $t \to 0^+$. Here are brief descriptions of the three methods.

1. Write $X_t = Y_t + Z_t$, where $Y_t$ is a compound Poisson process with Lévy measure $\nu$ restricted to $\mathbb{R} \setminus (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ for a sufficiently small $\varepsilon > 0$ (such that $f = 0$ on $[-2\varepsilon, 2\varepsilon]$), and $Z_t$ is the "remaining part" of $X_t$ (the existence of such decomposition follows from the Lévy–Itô theorem — see Theorem 19.2 in Sato's book on Lévy processes). Then $$t^{-1} \mathbb{E} |f(Y_t)| \to \int f(x) \nu(dx)$$ as $t \to 0^+$, as can be easily proved by conditioning on the number of jumps (only the term with a single jump has positive contribution). Furthermore, $$t^{-1} \mathbb{E} |f(X_t) - f(Y_t)| \leqslant t^{-1} \mathbb{P}[|Y_t| < \varepsilon] \mathbb{P}[|Z_t| > \varepsilon] + t^{-1} \mathbb{P}[|Y_t| \geqslant \varepsilon] \|f'\|_\infty \mathbb{E} |Z_t|$$ and both terms can be verified to converge to zero as $t \to 0^+$.
2. Use an appropriate variant of Plancherel's theorem: if $\psi = -\ln \varphi_\mu$ is the characteristic (Lévy—Khintchine) exponent, then $$t^{-1} \mathbb{E} f(X_t) = t^{-1} \mathbb{E} (f(X_t) - f(0)) = \int \hat{f}(z) t^{-1} (e^{-t \psi(z)} - 1) dz \to -\int \hat{f}(z) \psi(z) dz $$ by the dominated convergence theorem. Using the explicit form of $\psi$, the facts that $f'(0) = f''(0) = 0$, and again an appropriate variant of Plancherel's theorem, we can show that $$-\int \hat{f}(z) \psi(z) dz = \int f(x) \nu(dx),$$ as desired.
3. My favourite one, using semigroup theory. Let $L$ be the generator of the transition semigroup $P_t$ of $X_t$. We have $$t^{-1} \mathbb E f(X_t) = t^{-1} (\mathbb E f(X_t) - f(0)) = t^{-1} (P_t f(0) - f(0)) \to L f(0) $$ as $t \to 0^+$. By the expression for $L$ and the fact that $f(0) = f'(0) = f''(0) = 0$, we have $$L f(0) = \int f(x) \nu(dx).$$

I am pretty much sure one can find the above arguments in the literature, but I do not have a reference off the top of my head.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check these approaches. But what do you think about the approach I've described in my answer? Does it work and can we will the gaps?

Comment: I really like the third approach, since it is very easy to establish the desired result, once we know the form of the generator $L$. However, I need your help to understand some minor things. Let $\mu_t:=\mathcal L(X_t)$ for $t\ge0$. I know that the transition semigroup $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ of $X$ is given by $\kappa_t(x,B)=\mu_t(B-x)$ for all $(x,B)\in\mathbb R\times\mathcal B(E)$. Moreover, (as this is true for any Markov semigroup), $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ is contractive on any closed subspace $C$ of the space of bounded Borel measurable functions equipped with the supremum norm.

Comment: Let $L$ denote the $C$-generator of $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$. Note that for all $f\in\mathcal D(L)$ it holds $$\lim_{t\to0+}\frac{\kappa_tf-f}t=\kappa_0Af=Af$$ and since the convergence is wrt the supremum norm, it particularly holds $$\lim_{t\to0+}\frac{(\kappa_tf)(0)-f(0)}t=(Af)(0).$$ So, you don't need to consider the integral and argue with the dominated convergence theorem, unless I'm missing something. Now, the question is how we need to choose $C$.

Comment: **My guess is** that we can show that $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ is strongly continuous on the space $U_b(\mathbb R)$ of **uniformly** continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ and with that choice for $C$ it holds $$(Af)(x)=af''(x)+bf'(x)+cf(x)+\int f(y)-f(x)-1_{B_1(x)}(y-x)f'(x)\:\nu({\rm d}y)$$ for all $f\in U_b(\mathbb R)\cap C^2_b(\mathbb R)$ (maybe derivatives need to be uniformly continuous as well) for some $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: (a) Is this correct? (b) Am I missing something or is strong continuity of the semigroup not needed. (b) Everything should generalizes to arbitrary Hilbert spaces, but do you have a reference for the form of $L$ for the one-dimensional case considered here? (c) In any case, I'd still be interested on how we can fill the gaps in the approach described in my answer and would highly appreciate if you could comment on that as well.

Comment: (1) Your approach seems to be similar to item 1. in the above list, and I believe one can make it complete, but I had no time to think about it. (2) You are absolutely right that I overcomplicated item 3., I will edit the answer momentarily. (3) Indeed, transition semigroups of Lévy processes are strongly continuous on $U_b$, but in general the formula requires all of $f$, $f'$ and $f''$ to be $U_b$. (4) However, all you need here is that $P_t$ (that you call $\kappa_t$) is a Feller semigroup (i.e. strongly continuous on $C_0$, continuous functions vanishing at infinity).

Comment: Assuming that $\nu:=\mathcal L(X_1)$ has a finite first moment, is there a result yielding $\frac1tX_t\xrightarrow{t\to0+}\operatorname E[X_1]$ a.s.?

Comment: You mean: as $t \to \infty$, I suppose? This is a variant of the strong law of large numbers, I suppose. On the other hand, as $t \to 0^+$, I believe the random variables $t^{-1} X_t$ converge a.s. to the drift coefficient in the finite variation case.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my intend was a strong law of large numbers. We easily observe that $$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nf(Y_i)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\int f\:{\rm d}\nu\;\;\;\text{a.s. for all }f\in\mathcal L^p(\nu)\text{ and }p\ge1,$$ since $$Y_n:=X_n-X_{n-1}\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N$$ is an independent identically $\nu$-distributed process. I wondered whether there is a generalization of this observation.

Comment: Section 36 "Laws of large numbers" in Sato's book has Theorem 36.5, which is exactly the SLLN that you ask for in your previous comment. Regarding ergodicity in your last comment, a natural counterpart would be the Lévy–Itô decomposition, which in particular asserts that $Z_t = \sum_{s \leqslant t} f(X_s - X_{s-})$ is a Lévy process with Lévy measure $\nu \circ f^{-1}$, and hence $t^{-1} Z_t$ converges a.s. as $t \to \infty$ to $\mathbb{E} Z_1 = \int f d\nu$, of course given that $f$ is sufficiently "nice".

Comment: Sorry for replying to this old post, but there is some issue in your reasoning in (3.) which I'm not able to resolve. It's clear to me that $\frac1t\mu^{\ast t}\xrightarrow{t\to0+}f\xrightarrow{t\to0+}\lambda f$ (I write $\eta f:=\int f\:{\rm d}\eta$ whenever $\eta$ is a measure) for all $f\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d\setminus\{0\})$ (yes, we're dealing with $d=1$ in the question, but what I wrote before holds for an arbitrary infinitely divisible probaiblity measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lévy measure from the canonical decomposition of $\mu$).

Comment: However, by definition of vague convergence, we need to show $\frac1t\mu^{\ast t}\xrightarrow{t\to0+}f\xrightarrow{t\to0+}\lambda f$ for all $f\in C_c(\mathbb R^d)$. Since $\lambda(\{0\}=0$, it's clearly legitimate to pick $f\in C_c(\mathbb R^d\setminus\{0\})$ instead, but why is it even sufficient to assume $f$ is smooth?

Comment: I do not really remember the question, but (a) $t^{-1} \mu^{*t} f$ converges to infinity if $f(0) > 0$, even if the Lévy measure is zero; (b) for vague convergence of non-negative measures, it is sufficient to consider smooth functions: every continuous one can be squeezed between two smooth ones with arbitrary precision; (c) $t^{-1}\mu^{*t}$ converges to the Lévy measure vaguely on $\mathbb R^d\setminus\{0\}$, not on $\mathbb R^d$.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer**

Let

- $(b,\sigma)\in\mathbb R\times[0,\infty)$;
- $\nu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on $\mathbb R$ with $$\int1\wedge x^2\:\nu({\rm d}x)<\infty\tag a$$ and $\nu(\{0\})=0$;
- $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb R$ with $$\ln\varphi_\mu(t)={\rm i}tb-\frac{\sigma^2}2t^2+\int e^{{\rm i}tx}-1-1_{(-1,\:1)}(x){\rm i}tx\:\nu({\rm d}x)\tag b$$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$.

We can construct a real-valued random variable $Y$ on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $Y\sim\mu$ in the following way:

- Let $$I_k:=\left(-\frac1k,-\frac1{k+1}\right]\cup\left[\frac1k,\frac1{k+1}\right)$$ and $$\nu_k(B):=\nu(B\cap I_k)\;\;\;\text{for }B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$$ for $k\in\mathbb N$
- Note that $$\nu(I_0)+\int_{(-1,\:1)}\nu({\rm d}x)=\int1\wedge x^2\:\nu({\rm d}x)<\infty\tag c.$$
- Let $(X_k)_{k\in\mathbb N_0}$ be a real-valued independent process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with$^1$ $$X_k\sim\operatorname{CPoi}_{\nu_k}\;\;\;\text{for all }k\in\mathbb N_0\tag d.$$
- Note that $$\operatorname E[X_k]=\int_{I_k}\nu({\rm d}x)x\tag e$$ and $$\operatorname{Var}[X_k]=\int_{I_k}\nu({\rm d}x)x^2\tag f$$ for all $k\in\mathbb N_0$.
- It's easy to see that $$M_k:=\sum_{i=1}^k\left(X_i-\operatorname E\left[X_i\right]\right)\;\;\;\text{for }k\in\mathbb N$$ is a martingale with $$\operatorname E\left[M_k^2\right]=\sum_{i=1}^k\operatorname{Var}[X_i]\tag g\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N$$
- Let $\mathcal F^X_\infty:=\sigma(X_k:k\in\mathbb N)$.
- Then, $$\sup_{k\in\mathbb N}\operatorname E\left[M_k^2\right]=\int_{(-1,\:1)}\nu({\rm d}x)x^2<\infty\tag h$$ and hence $$M_k\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}M_\infty\;\;\;\text{almost surely}\tag i$$ for some real-valued $\mathcal F^X_\infty$-measurable square-integrable random variable $M_\infty$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ by the martingale convergence theorem.
- Now let $Z$ be a real-valued standard normally distributed random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ independent of $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$
- It's easy to show that $$Y:=b+\sigma Z+X_0+M_\infty\sim \mu.$$

Now we know that there characteristic exponent of $\mu^{\ast1/n}$ is similarly given by $$\ln\varphi_{\mu^{\ast1/n}}(t)={\rm i}tb^{(n)}-\frac{\left|\sigma^{(n)}\right|^2}2t^2+\int e^{{\rm i}tx}-1-1_{(-1,\:1)}(x){\rm i}tx\:\nu^{(n)}({\rm d}x)\tag j,$$ where $b^{(n)}:=b/n$, $\sigma^{(n)}:=\sigma/\sqrt n$ and $\nu^{(n)}:=\nu/n$, for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Define $\left(\nu^{(n)}_k,X^{(n)}_k,M^{(n)}_k,M^{(n)}_\infty,Y^{(n)}\right)$ in the same way as before, but with $(b,\sigma,\nu)$ replaced by $\left(b^{(n)},\sigma^{(n)},\nu^{(n)}\right)$.

We then [should be able to show](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3888621/47771) that for all $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2>0$, there are $k_0,n_0\in\mathbb N$ with $$p_{k_0}^{(n)}:=\operatorname P\left[\left|b^{(n)}+\sigma^{(n)}Z-\sum_{k=1}^{k_0}\operatorname E\left[X^{(n)}_k\right]\right|+\sum_{k>k_0}\left(X_k^{(n)}-\operatorname E\left[X_k^{(n)}\right]\right)>\varepsilon_1\right]\le\frac{\varepsilon_2}n\tag k$$ for all $n\ge n_0$.

Now let $$W^{(n)}:=\sum_{k=0}^{k_0}X_k^{(n)}\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N.$$

> In order to conclude that $n\mu^{\ast1/n}\to\nu$ vaguely, it is sufficient to show that $$n\operatorname P\left[Y^{(n)}\in(a,b]\right]\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\nu((a,b])\tag l$$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb R$ with $a<b$ and $\nu(\{a\})=\nu(\{b\})=0$.
>
> Using the simple estimate $\operatorname P\left[U\in(a+\varepsilon_1,b-\varepsilon_1]\right]-\operatorname P[|V|>\varepsilon_1]\le\operatorname P[U+V\in(a,b]]\le\operatorname P[U\in(a-\varepsilon_1,b+\varepsilon_1]]+\operatorname P[|V|>\varepsilon_1]$, for every random variables $U,V$, we obtain \begin{equation}\begin{split}&\operatorname P\left[W^{(n)}\in(a+\varepsilon_1,b-\varepsilon_1]\right]-p_{k_0}^{(n)}\\&\;\;\;\;\le\operatorname P[Y^{(n)}\in(a,b]]\\&\;\;\;\;\le\operatorname P[W^{(n)}\in(a-\varepsilon_1,b+\varepsilon_1]]+p_{k_0}^{(n)}\end{split}\tag m\end{equation} for all $n\ge n_0$. On the other hand, letting $J_{k_0}:=\bigcup_{k=0}^{k_0}I_k$, $$n\operatorname P\left[W^{(n)}\in B\right]=\nu(B\cap J_{k_0})\xrightarrow{k_0\to\infty}\nu(B)\;\;\;\text{for all }B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\tag n.$$ So, unless I'm missing something, we should be able to conclude **as long as** we can justify that we can take $k_0$ as large as desired, while maintaining $(k)$.
>
> **I would highly appreciated if someone could fill this gap.**

---

$^1$ One issue, which I'm unable to resolve at the moment, is that $\operatorname{CPoi}_{\eta}$ is only well-defined, when $\eta$ is a finite measure on $\mathbb R$, but (unless I'm missing something) the assumptions don't imply that $\nu_k$ is finite for all $k\in\mathbb N_0$. Since $\nu$ is arising from the Lévy-Khinchin formula, we may be able (I don't know whether this is true) to assume that $\nu$ is locally finite. Under this assumption, $\nu_k$ would be finite for all $k\ne0$ (since the support of $\nu_k$ is contained in $(-1,1)$ for $k\ne0$).

Comment: Some minor comments: 1. The integrand $x^2$ is missing under the integral in (c). 2. No need to invoke martingales, Kolmogorov's three-series theorem is enough. 3. Formula (j) in fact defines $\mu^{*s}$ for an arbitrary real $s > 0$ if $1/n$ is replaced by $s$.